# counting no of rows for each worksheet of a workbook

Tags: vba

I need some help with the below code. I am naive to this and need some help.

Problem:-

The below code is only counting for the sheet named in the formuale.

Requirement.
I want the that the code should count no of rows for each worksheet respectively and and return the outpput in next cells.

Code:-

```
Sub cou()

Dim w As Long
For w = 1 To Worksheets.count - 1
    With Worksheets(w)
        MsgBox (w)
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('NY MFG'!R1C1:R187C1)"
        Range("A2").Select
    End With
Next w


End Sub
```

Comment: Google `For each Worksheet vba`.

Comment: Thanks, I need the help with :- ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('NY MFG'!R1C1:R187C1)" to make it dynamic instead of working on one worksheet only

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA('" & Worksheets(w).Name & "'!R1C1:R187C1)"
```

Comment: @A.Gaurav if it worked then you should accept the answer.